# $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{5n}{3n^2-2k}$ without L'Hopital rule

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, limits-without-lhopital

The problem is:
Prove that sequence converges and find its limit if it's general term is: 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{5n}{3n^2-2k}$$
I tried monotone convergence theorem:
$$x_n \leqslant \frac{n \cdot 5n}{3n^2-2n}$$ and limit of it is $\frac{1}{3}$ but when I do $\frac{x_n+1}{x_n}$ I get $1$, but my answer should be bigger than $1$. Be simple, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easy to see
$$\frac{n \cdot 5n}{3n^2-2}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{5n}{3n^2-2}<\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{5n}{3n^2-2k}<\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{5n}{3n^2-2n}=\frac{n \cdot 5n}{3n^2-2n},$$
and $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n \cdot 5n}{3n^2-2}=\frac{n \cdot 5n}{3n^2-2n}=\frac{5}{3}.$$
So $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{5n}{3n^2-2k}=\frac{5}{3}.$$

Comment: So this is all I need? I don't need to find out if it is monotone rising or decreasing sequence?

Comment: yes, you really  don't need to find out that! Squeeze Theorem is what you need!

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciate it? Can you have a look at my other problem?

Comment: Where is your problem? try my best!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3279307/685632

Comment: It is very difficult  to estimate the lower bound ang upper bound in you problem math.stackexchange.com/q/3279307/685632 .And there are more better methods for your problem which are given bellow.

Comment: But we only learned squeeze and monotone convergence theoremss

Comment: The first method is not beyond your scope, just a formula!

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

$\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{5n}{3n^2-2k}
$

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{5n}{3n^2-2k}
&\gt \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{5n}{3n^2}\\
&= \frac{5n}{3n^2}\sum_{k=1}^n1\\
&= \frac{5}{3}\\
\end{array}
$

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{5n}{3n^2-2k}
&\lt \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{5n}{3n^2-2n}\\
& =\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{5}{3n-2}\\
& =\frac{5}{3-2/n}\\
& =\frac{5}{3-2/n}-\frac53+\frac53\\
& =\frac{15-(15-10/n}{3(3-2/n)}+\frac53\\
& =\frac{10}{3(3n-2)}+\frac53\\
& \to\frac53\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 1):

*Just added for your curiosity.*

Since you received good answers, let me try to work the partial sums
$$S_n= \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{5n}{3n^2-2k}=\frac 52 n\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\frac32n^2-k}$$

Using generalized harmonic numbers,
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1{a-k}=H_{-a}-H_{n-a}$$ Using the asymptotics
$$H_p=\gamma +\log \left({p}\right)+\frac{1}{2 p}-\frac{1}{12
   p^2}+\frac{1}{120 p^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^6}\right)$$ Using it twice with $a=\frac 32 n^2$, continuing with Taylor series and multiplying the result by $\frac 52 n$, we end with
$$S_n=\frac{5}{3}+\frac{5}{9 n}+\frac{65}{81 n^2}+\frac{40}{81 n^3}+\frac{106}{243
   n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$ which, for sure, shows the right limit but also allows a quite accurate approximation of the partial sums.

For example, $S_{10}=\frac{68014813111950755}{39297024420269616}\approx 1.73078787$ while the above truncated series would give $\frac{2102903}{1215000}\approx   1.73078436$.

Making the problem more general
$$T_n= \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{\alpha n}{\beta n^2-\gamma k}$$ doing the same would lead to
$$T_n=\frac{\alpha }{\beta }+\frac{\alpha  \gamma }{2 \beta ^2 n}+\frac{\alpha  \gamma 
   (3 \beta +2 \gamma )}{6 \beta ^3 n^2}+\frac{\alpha  \gamma ^2 (2 \beta +\gamma
   )}{4 \beta ^4 n^3}+\frac{\alpha  \gamma ^2 \left(5 \beta ^2+15 \beta  \gamma +6
   \gamma ^2\right)}{30 \beta ^5 n^4}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^5}\right)$$

Comment: Nice work, but I think you only need one parameter in $T_n$ with the term being $n/(n^2-ck)$.

Comment: @martycohen. Thanks for the nice words. For sure, only one term is sufficient; I just wanted to make the answer for the same structure as in the question. Cheers